# How do I set text after name in Facebook share post?

Tags: facebook, post, unity-game-engine, share

I am developing game in Unity & implementing share post like criminal case post.

I had heard about OG Tag.
og type is related to my question?

Please find sample image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those are called Open Graph Actions, you can read about them in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions

Custom Actions are deprecated though, as you can read in the docs.

Comment: I have shared a post from criminal case & cookie jam, it is working in that case.

How they managed to do it?

Comment: did you open the link? old apps can still use it until october 2017

Comment: Right. Thank You!